# Seventh Level or Level Seven

Tags: word-choice

Which is grammatically correct for a diploma,

> Full qualification at level seven of the Polish Qualifications Framework

or

> Full qualification at the seventh level of the Polish Qualifications Framework

?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Request for proofreading (including "which is right?" "is this correct?") are explicitly off-topic, although we can help you work through specific points of grammar or usage. Why do you think one or the other is "ungrammatical"? For what it's worth, either form is fine, but one may be *preferred* to the other by the diploma-granting institution, but even this would be an administrative matter and not a linguistic one. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

If the name is not specifically stated by the board, both ways are interchangeable. To be formal, I would use "seventh level".

Comment: Hello, QuartzX. Thanks for visiting ELU. However, as @tchrist, a moderator, has said, "We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers." Please visit the Help Center and check that this fits with site policy.

Answer (score 0):

Fully qualified at Level 7 of the Polish Qualifications Framework.

Comment: Hello, Zincha. Thanks for visiting ELU. However, as @tchrist, a moderator, has said, "We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers." Please visit the Help Center and check that this fits with site policy.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really about the English language, primarily: it's a question about **convention**, and as with all questions about convention, the right way is **the way that it is normally done**.

To see how it's normally done, one could use Google, and this is what I found, from a PDF guide to the Polish Qualifications Framework (PQF):
http://www.kwalifikacje.edu.pl/download/publikacje/PQF_UG.pdf

```
Examples:
L1U_K = PQF level 1, universal descriptor, knowledge
L4U_S = PQF level 4, universal descriptor, skills
L7U_C = PQF level 7, universal descriptor, social competence
```

So, you could say *"Full qualification at PQF (Polish Qualifications Framework) level 7."*  If level 7 happens to be the highest level you could possibly mention that too.

Comment: If it's not really about the English language primarily, I can't see how it's on-topic.